# How can I customize the UITableView that users see depending on which cell in the previous view they chose?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a navigation-based iOS application. In my `RootViewController`, users see chapters from 1 to 18. When they select a cell, it takes them to the `VersesViewController`, where they see another list from Verse 1 to whatever. Depending on what chapter they chose, they will see a different number of verses.

I would like to modify the contents of an `NSArray` in the `VersesViewController` when the user chooses a cell in the `RootViewController` view. How can I do this?

Here is the `RootViewController` code:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Chapters";
    chapterList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 1; i<19; i++)
    {
       [chapterList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chapter %d", i]];
    }

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [chapterList count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [chapterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    VersesViewController *detailViewController = [[VersesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VersesViewController" bundle:nil];

    if ([[chapterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Chapter 9"]) {
  [detailViewController setNumberOfVerses:18];
} else {
  [detailViewController setNumberOfVerses:72];
}
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.title = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [chapterList release];
}

@end
```

Please note that I am a n00b at Obj-C so I will need very simple answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more complex storage for your data. You can make array of dictionaries to describe all chapter's data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    chapterList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ...
    chapterInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Chapter 9", @"title", [NSNumber numberWithInt:18], @"numberOfVerses", nil];
    [chapterList addObject:chapterInfo];
    chapterInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Chapter 10", @"title", [NSNumber numberWithInt:72], @"numberOfVerses", nil];
    [chapterList addObject:chapterInfo];
    ...
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDictionary *chapterInfo = [chapterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [chapterInfo objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    VersesViewController *detailViewController = [[VersesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VersesViewController" bundle:nil];

    NSDictionary *chapterInfo = [chapterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [detailViewController setNumberOfVerses:[[chapterInfo objectForKey:@"numberOfVerses"] intValue]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];
}
```

The best would be to create plist file with description of all chapters and then load it like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"chapters" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *chaptersList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 2):

You should store the contents in a pList or some format. And then retrieve it according to which verse was pushed. Show us some code first so we can help you.